# Why do `__builtin_{{s,u}{add,sub,mul}ll_overflow` give a `long int` result instead of a `long long int` result?

Tags: c, gcc, clang

The `int` versions of the overflow-checking add/subtract/multiply builtins in GCC return an `int` result (good), and the `long int` versions return a `long int` result (also good), but the `long long int` versions return a `long int` result (not good). Why is this? It seems insane to me.

Example:

```
bool __builtin_uadd_overflow (unsigned int a, unsigned int b, unsigned int *res)
bool __builtin_uaddl_overflow (unsigned long int a, unsigned long int b, unsigned long int *res)
bool __builtin_uaddll_overflow (unsigned long long int a, unsigned long long int b, unsigned long int *res)
```

This is so broken, I can't even believe it. It means that on a target where `long` and `long long` are different sizes (for example, 32-bit ARM iOS targets), the `ll` versions of the functions are completely useless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in GCC that hasn't been fixed yet.

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65007

Comment: Wow. I'm amazed that clang duplicated the bug. I hope they actually fix it, rather than providing new functions and deprecating the broken ones.